# Does Nana (from the Ice Climbers) have her own percentage score?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

If I'm playing as Popo (ice climbers), any hits on Nana will not affect my percentage.  Does that mean that Nana has her own percentage score?  If she does, is there a way to tell what it is?

Comment: You just blew my mind...I never even thought of that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, Nana has her own percentage score. As it goes up, she'll become easier and easier for your opponents to kill, just like your own.

No, you can't tell what it is. Just pay close attention. If you both get hit by the same attack, judge the difference in distance between how far you went and how far she went and you can estimate based off that.

Comment: Keep in Mind that Nana does NOT DI

Comment: can you add it?